# Naming convention for methods which clear instance variable

Tags: ruby

What is a good naming convention for clearing an instance variable via a method. The actual value is stored in an array and the methods filter the array to find the value.

Here are methods I already have:

```
class Foo

  def initialize
    # Array of objects
    @data = []
  end

  # Get the variable or default value
  def variable
    @data.select { |o| o.attribute == 'Some Value' }.first || 'Default Value'
  end

  # Does the variable exist
  def variable?
    !!@data.select { |o| o.attribute == 'Some Value' }.first
  end

  # Does this make sense?
  def clear_variable!
    # Delete the variable
  end
end
```

Or should it be something like `delete_variable!`?

Comment: Interesting question. I have a question about it :) what? :P (I obviously don't know Ruby, but this seems interesting).

Comment: In Ruby you can't delete any variable, rather you can clear it..

Comment: You'll need to call that `@data` and put it inside an `initialize` method for this to actually work.

Comment: @tadman You're right. Poorly formed example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating something like that, it's best to emulate the conventional method names used within the most similar structure in Ruby. In this case, it's Hash:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @data = [ ]
    @default = 'Default Value'
  end

  def [](k)
    found = @data.find { |o| o.attribute == k }

    found ? found.value : @default
  end

  def has_key(k)?
    !!@data.find { |o| o.attribute == k }
  end

  # Does this make sense?
  def delete(k)
    @data.reject! { |o| o.attribute == k }
  end
end
```

Generally a method with `!` in it either raises exceptions if something goes wrong, it makes a permanent modification to the state of something (e.g. in-place modification methods), or both. It's not taken to mean "reset" or "clear".

Comment: The first part doesn't quite match what I'm looking for. The reason is because I'm looking for a specific object in an array. The last one may work.

Comment: The way you're using an array of objects as some kind of key-value store isn't especially efficient. It might be worth transforming `@data` to a Hash, use that internally, and export it in whatever format you need. Linear searches through large lists is brutally slow.

Comment: It actually isn't a large list. The list stores a number of widgets (arbitrary name) associated with the parent object. There can be any number of those widgets and there can be duplicates. A hash would be somewhat awkward.

Comment: If that's not practical, at least try and emulate the interface of Hash, where you have `def [](k)` to look up keys, `def []=(k,v)` to assign, and `def delete(k)` to remove things from it. See more about the interface [in the Hash documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html). It's always nice to have classes that work consistently regardless of how they're implemented internally. It fits in with the principle of duck-typing, where if it looks like a hash and works like a hash, it doesn't matter if it's actually something else.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a take based on your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `variable!` as making sense in a deletion context.  The ruby idiom for a method with an exclamation mark is that the method does something destructive to something else, yes, but it makes little sense in the context of a single variable.

e.g. `hash.merge!`, `record.save!` make sense, but `mymodel.field!` doesn't.

I'd suggest a name like `remove_field` or `unset_field` or, if you're clearing multiples, `clear!`.